# Trouble with Ubuntu 18.04 netplan bridge on hetzner server

Tags: 18.04, server, netplan, network-bridge

i need some help with an hetzner server, netplan and a network-bridge..

I want do setup an kvm under my ubuntu 18.04 hetzner server, who is reachable from outside. So i need a network-bridge.

So i have simulated the network configuration on a server hosted by my lokal VirtualBox, there i was able to setup an running network configuration with bridge. But i had to enable the promiscuous mode in the virtual box setting.

If i port the setting to my dedicatet hetzner ubuntu server, the internet conection from the server died..

Have somebody an tip for me?

Below the masked netplan config, which is not running (the netplan generate && netplan apply command work successfully).

default working network config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      addresses:
        - [IP4]
        - [IP6]
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: [another IP4]
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - [another IP4]
          - [another IP4]
          - [another IP4]
          - [another IP6]
          - [another IP6]
          - [another IP6]
```

Now my not working 'bridged-config':

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp2s0:
      dhcp4: false
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [enp2s0]
      addresses:
        - [IP4]
        - [IP6]
      routes:
        - on-link: true
          to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: [another IP4]
      gateway6: fe80::1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - [another IP4]
          - [another IP4]
          - [another IP4]
          - [another IP6]
          - [another IP6]
          - [another IP6]
```

Unfortunately this post dont solve my problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910941/9601604